# Two Actions With One onClick-React.js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, tags

In my react app, I've a `button(Reset)` and on the `onClick` attribute I want to make something happen simultaneously when `button` is clicked.

Is there any way(s) an `onClick` attribute can cause more than one actions to run —

1. Display all students(with details) on screen again and..
2. Clear the value of textbox and set it to its by default status i.e. asking end-user to enter something.

**What I tried**:

```
<input
  type="submit"
  value="Reset"
  onClick={() => {
    setSearchStu(student);
    document.getElementById("myTextbox").value = "";
  }}
/>;
```

And here is the working implementation of the above code.

`setSearchStu(student);` is resetting all student's data on screen and `document.getElementById("myTextbox").value = "";` is setting value to empty.

But this(above written) piece of code is displaying only students data and not clearing the text field.

On removing `setSearchStu(student);` from `input` tag, something like:

```
<input
  type="submit"
  value="Reset"
  onClick={() => {
    document.getElementById("myTextbox").value = "";
  }}
/>;
```

is working fine explicitly for clearing existing value and setting `textBox` to empty to enter something again. But this alone doesn't make any sense for me.

So how can I do the both tasks at the same time?

**"myTextbox" input**

```
<input
  type="text"
  value={userInput}
  onChange={(e) => setUserInput(e.target.value)}
  placeholder="Search here"
  id="myTextbox"
/>;
```

Comment: can you add the complete code of your component ? what is 'myTextbox'  ?  also when working with react , it is not recommended to query the DOM directly , what you can do is have another state for your input and just reset the input value via the state updater method .

Comment: You should not directly manipulate DOM when using react, instead in this case try using ref or state for the input fields.

Comment: Shyam, I updated my question with "myTextbox"

Answer (score 0):

You need to move your textbox value to state and manipulate it there. Because when you set value by using DOM react doesn't call a render and your component leave the previous view

Answer (score 0):

You are not showing your "myTextbox" input DOM in the question, anyway you need add value and onChange props to it like this:

```
<input 
 type="text" 
 value={myText} 
 onChange{(event) => setMyText(event.target.value)} />
```

and you need to add this React state in your component:

```
const [myText, setMyText] = React.useState("")
```

**EDIT**
change the input button to:

```
<button
  type="submit"
  value="Reset"
  onClick={() => {
    setUserInput("");
  }}
/>;
```

If you cannot implement this because your text input is located in a different component then you have some options:

- if it's located in a child component then pass the myText and setMyText as props to the child component and use them like this `props.myText` and `props.setMyText`.
- if the the input field and the button are located in a totally different components away from each others then I recommend you to learn a global state management system like Redux.js or something...

Comment: Hasan, I updated my question with "myTextbox"

Comment: I also edited my answer, be aware that {document.getElementById("myTextbox").value = ""} won't change the userInputState.... you need to call setUserInputState with the button onClick

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve two actions with a single onClick() by using a separate function.

```
const searchAndClear=()=>
{
setSearchStu(student);
document.getElementById("myTextbox").value = "";
}

<input
  type="submit"
  value="Reset"
  onClick={searchAndClear}
/>;
```